# Регулярные выражения: не обнаруживает конец и начало строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Один дефис в начале строки, затем какие угодно символы и так до конца строки.
Когда начнётся новая строка, нужно искать следующее совпадение:

```
/^-{1}(.*)$/g

-Строка1-1
-Строка2-2
```

В примере выше совпадений нет, однако с регулярным выражением `/-{1}(.*)/g` будет два совпадения, если начать с новой строки. Это как раз то, что нужно,  но я не понимаю, почему это работает, а `/^-{1}(.*)$/g` - нет.

[Ссылка на исходник](https://regex101.com/r/unj0yT/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-первых, `-{1}` избыточно, достаточно `-`.

Во-вторых, `^` и `$` подразумевают начало и конец всей строки (string), а не подстроки, разбитой `\n` (line). Поставьте в опциях флажок `m` (multi line).

В-третьих, `$` избыточно, потому что `.*` будет глотать символы до первого переноса строки, если не указать модификатор `s` (single line).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!